# showing multiple rows with jquery

Tags: jquery, each, multiple-results

I have an HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="show"></div>
```

And a JQuery:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'query2.php',
            data: key,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {

                var tmp = "";
                $.each(msg, function (i, v) {

                    tmp += ('<div class="cell">' + v.jobTitle + '</div>');
                    tmp += ('<div class="cell">' + v.jobName + '</div>');
                    tmp += ('<div class="cell">' + v.fullName + '</div>');
                    tmp += ('<div class="cell">' + v.phone + '</div>');
                    tmp += ('<div class="cell">' + v.mail + '</div>');
                    tmp += ('<div class="cell">' + v.city + '</div>');
                    tmp += ('<div class="cell">' + v.description + '</div>');

                    $('#show').html(tmp);
                    alert(tmp);

                });
```

If i have on row in my query the result would be:

[image]

But if i have more rows, It get messy and all would show in one row:

[image]

**How can i show another row with class="row" in my loop?**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: By using the solution given in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581177/showing-array-with-jquery) to the same problem...

Comment: And it didn't resolved and i updated it and no one replied!!! So i asked it again in order to place the answer there too.
Thanks by the way.

Comment: I still don't understand what needs to be accomplished.